# how to rename multiple files with inserts from a list

Tags: bash, unix

I have hundreds of numbered files

```
file_001.txt

file_002.txt

file_003.txt
...
```

and and the same number of letters in a separate file

letters.txt:

```
abc

def

ghi
...
```

How can I rename the files in this way:

```
file_001_abc.txt
file_002_def.txt
file_003_ghi.txt
```

Thanks in advance, very much!

Comment: Interesting little problem but have you made any attempt to solve it yourself? If so, please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `paste` and `awk` came to my mind first.

```
paste files.txt letters.txt | awk '{split($1,file,"."); print file[1]"_"$2"."file[2]}'
```

If you do not have a list of the files you could replace `files.txt` for example by `<(ls -1)` but this depends on your specific setup.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful and solved my task in combination with Abubaker Siddiques answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
for i in `cat f1`;do
let count++
var=$(head -$count letters.txt | tail -1)
mv $i ${i%.txt}_$var.txt
done
```

Hope this helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I commented the line with xargs so you can check the script.
When you like it, remove the comment.

```
start=0
while read next; do
   (( start = start + 1 ));
   printf "mv file_%03d.txt file_%03d_%s.txt\n" ${start} ${start} ${next}
   # printf "file_%03d.txt file_%03d_%s.txt" ${start} ${start} ${next} | xargs mv
done < letters.txt
```